# RegionPlot3D not showing 2D shapes

Tags: plotting

I am trying to draw a series of regions in Mathematica (one example below), but the planes I am trying to draw with `RegionPlot3D` don't show anything.

For example,

```
RegionPlot3D[((p2 < 247/561 && 
     1/147 (73 - 117 p2) <= p1 <= 1/12 (11 - 21 p2)) || (p2 == 247/
      561 && p1 == 82/561)) && p3 == 1/10 (-1 + 2 p1 + 11 p2), 
{p1,0,1}, {p2,0,1}, {p3, 0, 1}]
```

doesn't yield/show anything in the plot, but if I change `p3 == 1/10 (-1 + 2 p1 + 11 p2)` to `p3 >= 1/10 (-1 + 2 p1 + 11 p2)`, then I get a (crudely drawn) 3D region.

Is there another 3D plotting option that you would recommend, or a way to make `RegionPlot3D` show 2d planes, but still in a 3 dimensional plot?

(I'm using Version 11 on Linux Mint)

Comment: If you're have an issue with something, please include your operating system with version and the version of Mathematica you are using, e.g. `$Version`.

Comment: I have a similar problem in Mathematica 11.3, ArchLinux.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I think I ended up solving my issue by using ParametricPlot3D instead.

Comment: I have a similar problem I have `r = ParametricRegion[{(-1 + p0)^2, 2 (-1 + p0) p0 (-1 + p1), 
  p0 (p0 + 2 p1 - 2 p0 p1)}, {{p0, 0, 1}, {p1, 0, 1}}]` then `Region[r]` returns an image but `RegionPlot3D[r]` only an empty box. `$Version` produces `11.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)`